# Using javascript for dynamic php drop down (url)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, selection

I have javascript code that fires once I select from first drop down:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first-choice").change(function() {
        $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("select#first-choice").filter(":selected").val());
    });
});
```

I think the problem lies when I create the getter.php extension... Which I use choice in my sql. Choice is defined in getter.php as:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT name, code FROM sets WHERE name='$choice'");
$sth->execute();
$choicecode = $sth->fetchColumn(1);
```

When the javascript change fires I get an empty drop down. So I tested by setting Choice equal to one first-choice options, instead of $_GET, and the second list populated correctly. So I'm assuming my error comes from my js by defining the selected first choice.

Comment: Is that all of `getter.php`? Where do you render the new select? It looks like there is no output from this file at all.

Comment: @MatthewRapati No, there is more for rendering, but I am 100% sure the error does not lie in getter.php, like I said I changed the value of "choice" to a known value instead of $_get and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in your change function

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $(this).val();
});
```

or

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice option:selected").val();
});
```

or use find

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").find(":selected").val();
});
```

Make sure you have entered the value in option's value attribute

```
<option value="test">test</option>
```

Comment: The first option worked. I have never seen that before. So basically  "this" can be used for the change function. IS there a way I can later define the first selected and selected options so i could plug them into a database?

Comment: `$(this)` will have the object of current element triggered like if you select 3rd option it will have a object of third option

Comment: So I just found an error, where that if there is a spacing in-between the selection name, the the $_get doesn't seem to work either...any way of fixing this?

Comment: is value and option text is same then you can select `$(this).text()` match in database by the option text

Comment: what about the $_GET error I'm having, it must be adding in something to account for the spaces in some of my selection names

Comment: @ramboramos can you show the full code of select box and dataset from database post it in your question or ask as new question with full description